# “TeXmacs” is damaged and can’t be opened

Tags: apple-silicon

When I download the texmacs dmg (`TeXmacs-2.1.1-arm.dmg`) to install in the Apple M1 chip Mac Book Pro, shows thiserror:

```
“TeXmacs” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should eject the disk image.
```

[image]

Why did this happen? What should I do to fix this problem? I have already tried to download the file like this to make sure the file downloaded completely:

```
➜  Downloads wget -c https://www.texmacs.org/Download/ftp/tmftp/macos/TeXmacs-2.1.1-arm.dmg
--2022-04-02 20:27:29--  https://www.texmacs.org/Download/ftp/tmftp/macos/TeXmacs-2.1.1-arm.dmg
Resolving www.texmacs.org (www.texmacs.org)... 193.55.176.20
Connecting to www.texmacs.org (www.texmacs.org)|193.55.176.20|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable

    The file is already fully retrieved; nothing to do.
```

Still did not fix this problem. Any solution?

Comment: Did you try removing the file and then running `wget https://...`?

Comment: either the source is damaged or the thing that *downloaded* the source did something wrong. Try a different method of downloading (web browser or 2...) and/or try downloading from elsewhere, if possible.

Comment: Thank you! I delete the legacy file and redownload the dmg and works.@nohillside